# Voltage drop, direction of current, extra voltage source

Tags: voltage

This is a branch from a network, and -40mA flowing through it (direction shown below). Textbook says the voltage drop on the 45 ohm resistor is -3.18V. But I don't understand it.
Do I need to add that extra 2 Volts from the extra source or substitute it?
So the question (in short): how do you calculate the -3.18V here exactly? (and why that way)
[image]

Full schematic from link provided by the OP in the comments:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that's not a typo of some sort? If the current is defined through a circuit with no branches, you are limited to V=IR by definition. Is this part of some superposition? With the information given it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Ok this is the problem: http://imgur.com/CnAkTzp But of course I dont expect you to solve it. The current in the "big loop" as I calculated is ~-40mA. As shown above

Comment: -40mA is wrong, then

Comment: According to the schematic at the link you've provided above, \$I_1\$ is *not* the current through the 45 ohm resistor but is, rather, the sum of that current and the current through the 70 ohm resistor in the rightmost branch.

Comment: Maybe I sound stupid here but are these notations equivalent: http://imgur.com/KnHD79J ? I cant find any info on google  (Sorry, I wanted a *vertical* minus sign in there)

Comment: No, I think you need to swap "+" and "-" for the left symbol for them to be equivalent.

Comment: Note https://books.google.com/books?id=JhkgMq_vjmkC&pg=PA233 for example.

Comment: @RespawnedFluff Interesting, I solved some problems with this program: www.circuitlab.com and It appears to be the contrary what you linked. In other worlds, in my picture the equation is correct.

Comment: I don't quite follow which picture you're talking about, but I'm glad to hear that you figured it out. Did you find the problem in a book that used the latter source notation, i.e. shown on the right in http://imgur.com/KnHD79J?

Comment: FWIW, in LTspice I get -1.7894V as the potential of the top of that resistor relative to the bottom of it. And if I swap all the sources around I get minus that, i.e. 1.78941V. I get -3.78941V from  from the left ("-") node of the source next to it to ground (with the sources orientation you have).

Comment: http://imgur.com/EMWPJ8Y

Comment: @RespawnedFluff  Thanks, I scanned the problem just to show you: http://imgur.com/KsAjnAZ  We denote V with "U". So it seems the book have an error. Frustrating..

Comment: Even if I flip around the voltage sources but keep the current source as in the book, I still cannot get their result (I get -2.21V), so there must be an error in the book's solution. That's why [text]books have errata.

Comment: I can actually get a somewhat integer answer if I change the left voltage source to 3V, which then gives -2.7V answer. And if I change it to 4V, I do get -3.187V as a result http://imgur.com/95PjAH5. So I'm guessing that must have been the typo (or something equivalent with that). By the way, from what I see in the answer key snippet, it seems this textbook uses horrible values for components in all problems, meaning you have to use a calculator for every problem to get the numerical result... which is generally pretty bad pedagogy.

Comment: @RespawnedFluff  Interesting, you actually swapped the direction of the two voltage sources, but not the current source, then you raised the left one to 4V and you get the answer. This is weird. I checked it and you are right. This is when Mulder comes in from X-files :https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MkMKzdTBEOc

Comment: It's not exactly the answer, they expect 3.17 (and I got 3.187), but is the closest I could think of. It would help if you showed a very simple problem from that book and its answer [they must have something like that early on] so we can figure out the exact convention it uses for sources.

Comment: @RespawnedFluff  I think what you did there (you got 3.18V) is just pure luck. I scanned a simple problem, and it's solution:  http://imgur.com/lbOVRKe

Comment: Yeah, they got something backwards relative to that UK textbook. Either the notation for the voltage sources or [the sign convention for the current through passive components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passive_sign_convention#Sign_conventions). The latter would be even more strange, but not unheard of.

Answer (score 1):

My solution to the problem is:
48mA (409/8500) going through the 6.75V and its 45ohm resistor.
-8.4mA (-71/8500) going through the 4V and the 70ohm resistor.
-40mA (169/4250) going through the 2V, the 20ohm and the 45ohm resistors.
The 5V and the 37ohm can be ignored as their ends are connected, hence no overall P.D across them.
These all add up to give a voltage (taking the top right corner to be 0V) of 4.58V in the "H" shaped bit in the bottom left corner.

As Filkor and I have both got -40mA for the current, it's probably safe to assume the textbook got this part right.
Where it got -3.18V from is a mystery as the correct is -0.75V (V=IR=-0.040*45), which will always be the voltage across any 45ohm resistor when -40mA is flowing through it, regardless of how ridiculous the rest of the circuit is.

My conclusion therefore: I say you should stuff the textbook